# Copying files built on Unix back to Windows Jenkins workspace

Tags: windows, unix, ssh, jenkins

I have a jenkins Job in which I build my application on Unix box by making SSH connection to it and run the build script on Unix box. My Jenkins is on windows I want to generate PMD reports on windows so, i want to copy pmd.xml file from Unix box to Windows machine.
Right now my windows Jenkins workspace is empty because I do SVN checkout, Build and generation of binaries on Unix box. for this purpose I am using Jenkins SSH plugin.
Is there any way to copy Unix contents back to Windows Jenkins Workspace?
I have tried Jenkins SCP plugin but confused with source and SCP site. Please suggest.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `plink.exe` and `pscp.exe` to interface from Windows to Linux. These should be part of your [**PuTTY distribution**](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html).

However, if your slave is already connecting to the Linux machine, you can use the same connection to bring the file back to slave's workspace. Then use [**Copy to Slave**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+To+Slave+Plugin) plugin (nevermind the name, it does both directions) to move the file from slave to master workspace

Comment: Thanks Slav, But I dont have any master-slave combination I have a jenkins installed on Windows machine and it makes connection to Unix machin by SSH plugin. I want to transfer files which got generated on Unix to My Windows Jenkins Workspace.

Comment: From Execute Windows Batch Command `plink.exe -pw password root@remote.ip:/path/to/remote/file %WORKSPACE%\path\to\local\file\ `

Comment: Thanks your suggestion was valuable.

Answer (score 0):

I Added Linux machine as slave to windows master and then used Copy-to-Slave plugin to copy generated reports from linux to windows workspace its working fine.